# Is there a way to force images on the "metaslider" plugin to to load using HTTPS instead of the default HTTP

Tags: wordpress, plugins, https

I am using the Metaslider wordpress plugin http://wordpress.org/plugins/ml-slider/ and I have installed an SSL Certificate. however the page where the slideshow is, tells me there are some insecure elements on the page. These elements are the images from the slide that load using HTTP by default. Is there a way to force them to load using HTTPS?

Answer (score 1):

Just change your default addresses to http:// at settings > general. Wordpress plugins that force https won't do with metaslider

Answer (score 0):

you can run some sort of function like this on that specific page.

in your functions.php

```
<?php
function filter_content_match_protocols( $content ) {
    $search = $replace = get_bloginfo( 'home' );

    if ( ! preg_match( '|/$|', $search ) )
        $search = $replace = "$search/";

    if ( is_ssl() ) {
        $search = str_replace( 'https://', 'http://', $search );
        $replace = str_replace( 'http://', 'https://', $replace );
    }
    else {
        $search = str_replace( 'http://', 'https://', $search );
        $replace = str_replace( 'https://', 'http://', $replace );
    }

    $content = str_replace( $search, $replace, $content );

    return $content;
}
ob_start( 'filter_content_match_protocols' );

function filter_content_match_protocols_end() {
    ob_end_flush();
}
add_action( 'shutdown', 'filter_content_match_protocols_end', -10 );
?>
```